# Jar file created by IntelliJ won't run outside of the IDE (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I build a JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDE, and try to build executable Jar using built in artifacts. The output jar can be executed using `Right Click` -> `Run 'Java_Playground.jar'` and runs perfectly. However, if I try to execute the jar in terminal by `java -jar Java_Playground.jar` I got error message of

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.MainApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I have the `MANIFEST.MF` generated by IntelliJ in `src/main/META-INF/` and I have tried setting it up by manually in `src/main/resources/META-INF/` and both generate the same error.

I have tried specified the `Class-Path` in the `MANIFEST.MF` with `.` and same error.

I have checked the output jar by unarchive it and it does contain the `main.MainApp.class` and the correct `MANIFEST.MF` along with all other classes.

Sample code is below:

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.MainApp
```

MainApp

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private ObservableList<Person> personObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public MainApp() {
        personObservableList.add(new Person("aaa", "1234", "WS"));
        personObservableList.add(new Person("bbb", "2345", "S"));
        personObservableList.add(new Person("ccc", "3456", "WS"));
        personObservableList.add(new Person("ddd", "4567", "L"));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data as an observable list of Person
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonObservableList() {
        return personObservableList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
\*
Rest of code
*/
}
```

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Looks like JavaFX was not packaged into the jar. Notice that [from Java 11 onward, JavaFX is no longer packaged with the JDK](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html).

Comment: I then follow this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html#java_fx_build_artifact) on IntelliJ page to build an artifact of JavaFx Application, but exact same error occurs. Any idea how can I package JavaFX in to the Jar? Thanks.

Comment: When packaged in the JAR with your application, JavaFX ends up on the class-path. Technically that configuration is not supported and, since JavaFX 16, a warning is actually emitted. However, everything should still work except for one caveat: _Your main class cannot be assignable to `Application`_. Create a separate main class whose main method simply calls `Application.launch(MainApp.class, args)`. That all being said, you may want to look into alternative deployment strategies (e.g. `jlink` or `jpackage`).

Comment: Hi, I then create a class `Driver` with one `public static void main(String[] args) {Application.launch(MainApp.class, args) }` but same error occurs (Instead, this time it's an exception of `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`).

Same thing of runnable in IntelliJ but not in teminal.

Comment: @Slaw Looking closely into what you suggested along with some search on internet, I am able to run the jar file by `java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls -jar Java_Playground.jar`
To run this, first need to download [Link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) JavaFX SDK as it's not included in Java 16. And then `export PATH_TO_FX=<path>/<sdk>/lib`. Then the above command can be used to run the jar outside of IDE. For anyone who runs into similar problem, I hope this helps. And I will look into other deployment strategies since this is not ideal still. Thanks for help.